# Influx 1.8 Flux: are there more meaningful error messages than "Error: unknown server error: 500 Internal Server Error"?

Tags: influxdb, flux

I'm struggling with influxdb 1.8 with Flux enabled trying to create some queries using the command line tool "influx".

Well, i got very often the error message: "500 Internal Server Error" and i don't know what actually went wrong.

I wonder, if there is more detailed information available and how can i get it?
I'm talking about "syntax error in position...", "missing argument...", "invalid argument..."  and so on.

with best Regards,
Peter